# bash: split a long comma-separated list to two parts

Tags: bash, list, split

I have a bash script which reads a list of comma-and-space-separated server names from an external command:

```
server_0.example.com, server_1.example.com, ..., server_70.example.com
```

The script should run an external command which accepts a server list in that form, but limited to 50 servers at a time. Therefore, I need to split it to two lists with roughly the same size:

```
server_0.example.com, server_1.example.com, ..., server_35.example.com
```

and

```
server_35.example.com, server_36.example.com, ..., server_70.example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an approach:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) printf "%s, ", $i} <-- prints first half
         {printf "\n"} <--- prints new line
         {for (i=NF/2+1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s, ", $i}  <-- prints second half
         {printf "\n"} <--- prints new line
        '
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) printf "%s, ", $i} {printf "\n"} {for (i=NF/2+1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s, ", $i} {printf "\n"}' <<< "server_0.example.com, server_1.example.com, ..., server_70.example.com"
server_0.example.com,  server_1.example.com, 
 ...,  server_70.example.com,
```

---

### Update

Not to skip one value when NF is odd:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=int(NF/2); i++) printf "%s, ", $i} <-- prints first half
         {printf "\n"} <--- prints new line
         {for (i=int(NF/2)+1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s, ", $i}  <-- prints second half
         {printf "\n"} <--- prints new line
        '
```

Comment: Apologies for nitpicking: this might omit a field given an *odd* number of fields.

Comment: No problem... but really? Given for example `NF=7`, first loop will be `(i=1; i<=3...)` and the second `(i=4; i<=7...)`.

Comment: Gosh, I thought the results of divisions in the `for` expressions were always integer.

Comment: Updated with `int(NF/2)`. It should be fine now (tested). Thanks, @devnull!

Comment: Yup, it'd work well now.  (Testing ain't required for the modified version :)